# Handling Ambiguous time With day light saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on ASP.Net Project using Visual Studio 2019 , In one of the Forms  there is a field to get date time from user  and  I'm sending that data to another method " ConvertDateTime" which convert  date and time to eastern time and save it to data base , when retrieving  eastern time  convert back to users time zone .in  Day light Saving time  how to handle ambiguous time with the  method mentioned below.

```
 public static DateTime ConvertDateTime(DateTime time, IPTimeZoneInfo tzInfo)
        {

            if (!tzInfo.Initialized)
            {
                throw new HttpException("Timezone info structure not initialized.");
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tzInfo.WinID)) // New adjustment using Dynamic DST
            {
                TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzInfo.WinID);

                if (!tzInfo.AutoAdjustDst && tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime && tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(time))
                    time = time.AddHours(1.0);

                // In case the time is invalid in the course time zone, increment until the next valid minute
                while (tzi.IsInvalidTime(time))
                    time = time.AddMinutes(1);

                time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

                return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, tzi, ServerTimeZoneInfo);
            }
            double hourOff = tzInfo.HourOffset;

            if (!tzInfo.AutoAdjustDst && time.IsDaylightSavingTime())
            {
                hourOff -= 1.0;
            }

            if (time.Year < 100)
            {
                time = time.AddYears(time.Year < 70 ? 2000 : 1900);
            }

            return time.AddHours(-hourOff);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend server side time handling to be UTC regardless of the servers time zone. It should really only be converted for the end user and display. This also means that if your server is moved to a different time zone, which is pretty common with cloud servers now, then your project will still work correctly.

.NET time handling routines are all based around UTC and if you use the library methods ConvertTimeToUTC and ConvertTimeFromUTC the resulting time will automatically handle the local time zones daylight saving time.

[Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/performing-arithmetic-operations?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I also want to know the answer. This is very important